# Intel XDK Image Upload

Tags: intel-xdk

I'm trying to upload an image on Intel XDK

```
intel.xdk.file.uploadToServer(pictureURL,"http://www.myserver.com/uploadImage.php", "", "image/jpeg",
```

but the image doesn't seem to upload to the server even though i get a success from the callback, anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @Rodney0 Why are you using a php script cannot you just use a jpg or png link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways to upload file to server. at all this is a 2way action.

maybe file has been uploaded but an error has occurred in server. you can use fail callback and got the error.

```
, function (error) { alert(JSON.stringify(error)); });
```

or maybe an undefined value cause error andbreaks the next line.

using ajax calls, httpRequest are standard ways which has many references